# Cross Layout View

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

i'm looking for a way to display an "overlay" view across multiple layouts (As scribbled in the attached image)[image: Tablet Screen with multiple layouts (Header,List,Detail)].

My research showed that layouts can only live inside other layouts and that there is no such concept of overlay layout. Is that possible? Any suggestions?

Many thanks! Kay.

Comment: you want the keep the layout over the another layout ?

Comment: Yes. the View displaying "Overlay" is the topmost view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrameLayout is the only layout that kan render overlapping Views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Primary View Primary View Primary View Primary View" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="OverLap" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So the list and the detail view must live inside a frame layout?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to show a view or layout element over layout.
in case you should use FrameLayout like this

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                Your layout

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                Your view element to float or overlay 

            </LinearLayout>             


</FrameLayout>
```